# android ArrayList iterator

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use an iterator on an ArrayList ( to get rid of a for loop, don't ask me why... ), however I need to skip the process of one of the arrays upon a boolean condition , should I still use an index and a break ???

```
// INTERPOLATION
int i = 0;
Iterator<CircularFifoQueue<SensorEvent>> buf = samplingFifoQueues.iterator();
while (buf.hasNext()) {
    if ( i == 2 && !mDeviceSensorGyro) {  // skip this queue if no gyroscope in device
       break;
    }               
    // proceed
   buf.next();
   i++;
}
```

thanks for help

Comment: Do you want to continue over to the next element's processing or just want to break completely out of it?

Comment: @PopoFibo skip means skip, doesn't it?

Comment: @Gangnus  well it does yes but the statement wasn't perfectly clear to me hence the comment, doesn't that align to the correct usage of the comments section after all?

Comment: @PopoFibo In comments it is skip, too. in CODE there is a break, yes. The task is set by words, code IS incorrect, according to the questionner.

Comment: @Gangnus sir yes sir :)

Comment: @PopoFibo I'm sorry, but when I try to be polite here, at once there is somebody who punishes me for that. Politeness is considered excessive by oldies. Or rather, politeness should show itself in correct answers and comments and just voting, ONLY. So *sigh*, I have forgotten my manners. My excuses, Sir.

Comment: @Gangnus No worries at all sir, I definitely understand that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
// INTERPOLATION
int i = 0;
Iterator<CircularFifoQueue<SensorEvent>> buf = samplingFifoQueues.iterator();
while (buf.hasNext()) {
    if ( i != 2 || mDeviceSensorGyro) {  // skip this queue if no gyroscope in device
       // proceed  
    }               

    buf.next();
    i++;
}
```

But I would rather attach some attribute to the queue elements to check for it. Work directly with numbers is bad practice.

Comment: this will work fine... however I inserted a test  buf.isEmpty() to skip it, if it doesn't exist there are no data captured...

Comment: @erwin Of course. It is a normal practice to have many conditions under which the different branches are taken inside and out of the cycle.